# how to set the view box of an svg such that it is viewable in the browser

Tags: css, svg

I have this

```
d3.xml("https://crossorigin.me/https://svgshare.com/i/5w9.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
  if (error) throw error;
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
  let test = document.querySelector('svg')
  test.setAttribute("viewBox", "-100 -100 200000 60000"); 
});
```

also seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/c6jvzc19/24/

My hope is that it would scale the height and width so that 200,000 units of width and 60,000 units of height would scale to show in the normal view box. As you can see though, the svg is still too impossibly big to see - you really have to scroll a lot before you can start seeing stuff.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding how this view box attribute works. What should it be instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you needed to set the `width` and the `height` right before appending the `svg` to the `document,

```
xml.documentElement.setAttribute("width", "100%");  
xml.documentElement.setAttribute("height", "100%");

document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/c6jvzc19/30/